# How does the attenuation coefficient of white light in water compare to the attenuation coefficient of monochromatic light in water?

Tags: optics, scattering, radiation, absorption

So, from what I understand, different wavelengths of visible light, when shone through water, will have different attenuation coefficients due to scattering and absorption from the water molecules. This means that blue light would have a higher attenuation coefficient (since it gets scattered most) right? So, does this mean that white light would have a higher attenuation coefficient than light composed of only one wavelength? Would it mean that white light's attenuation coefficient is just like the weighted average of the attenuation coefficients of each wavelength? Please answer if you can.

Comment: The attenuation of white light is not a well defined concept. Dispersion affects the spectral composition of light. If the ingoing light is defined as white, then the outgoing light no longer is exactly white.

Comment: It is why sunsets are red and why the sky is blue.

Answer (score 2):

You are right: White light’s total attenuation coefficient is an average of that for the individual frequency components, weighted by the spectral power in each component.

Comment: So if you have two light sources with the same total power, one blue and the other white, the white light would be less attenuated.

Comment: @Not_Einstein Not necessarily! If blue is the least attenuated color in the spectrum, then the white light would on average be attenuated more.

Comment: But your assumption was that blue light is more highly attenuated.

Comment: @Not_Einstein Sometimes blue light is more attenuated than the rest of the spectrum, sometimes less!